how can i do responsive layout android studio
how can do  a responsive layout on android studio i tryed a lot of méthodes non of them had Works and layout does not work same as  in the emulator and xml and the color does not show the same
i tryed change layout size (small,enter image description herenormal,large)

Too broad a question, with too many potential answers.  Come back with a specific problem you're having and your code that's causing it and you can probably get some help.
